# Closed: vanishing data in Google Form after refreshing the page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I wrote a google script, which is creating form, using data from google spreadsheet. I'm using drop-down answer options. The code works normally, all data appears, but sometimes ( 3 times of 5 attempts), after refreshing browser page, some questions disappeared. Everytime it's different question, so it isn't problem with specific question.
What is the problem and how can i fix it?

UPD: Solved. Problem was in opened Google Form while code was compiled.

```
function myFunk(){
    var SHEET_ID = FormApp.getActiveForm().getDestinationId();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID);
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var numb = sheets[1].getLastRow();

    var TypeSelect = form.addListItem()
        .setRequired(true);
    var TypeChoices = getData(TypeSelect,sheets[1],1,numb)
    TypeSelect.setChoices(TypeChoices);

    var ClientSelect = form.addListItem()
        .setRequired(true)
    var ClientChoices = getData(ClientSelect, sheets[1],2,numb)
    ClientSelect.setChoices(ClientChoices);

    var phases = ["Start","End"];
    var PhasesChoices=[];
    var PhaseSelect = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
        .setRequired(true);
    for (var t=0;t<phases.length; t++){
      PhasesChoices.push(PhaseSelect.createChoice(phases[t]));
    }
    PhaseSelect.setChoiceValues(phases);
}

function getData(DataSelect,sheet,numbColumn,lRow){
    var DataChoices = [];
    var DataValues =  sheet.getRange(2,numbColumn,lRow,1).getValues()
         .filter(CheckFull);
    var data = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < DataValues.length; i++) {
      data.push(DataValues[i]);
    }
    for(var j =0; j < data.length; j++) {
      DataChoices.push(DataSelect.createChoice(data[j]));
    }
 return DataChoices;
}

function CheckFull(value){
    return value != '';
}
```

Comment: Welcome. The code included isn't complete as the form creation statement isn't include as well the statement that call myFunk function. Also details of the spreadsheet are missing. Is it being edited while you are creating your forms? Ref. [mcve].

Comment: Yep, you are wright, the problem was about form was opened for editing while code was compiled

Comment: So do you still have a problem or is it solved now?

Comment: I can see that your range is `(2,numbColumn,lRow,1)`, but the correct syntax is `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`. The number of rows is (last row- first row+1), so in your case `lRow-1`.

Comment: Problem is solved, thanks